# How to cite an interview in APA with multiple interviewees?

Tags: citations, apa

I need to cite an interview with multiple interviewees in APA format, but the APA website only has an example with a [single interviewee](https://apastyle.apa.org/learn/faqs/cite-interview).

I can't find any other resources online; does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply take the interview citation you referred to and replace the single author with the accepted method of citing multiple authors.

---

From page 175, 6.12 One Work by Multiple Authors (from my physical copy):

> When a work has two authors, cite both names every time the reference occurs in text. When a work has three, four, or five authors, cite all authors the first time, the reference occurs; in subsequent citations, include only the surname of the first author followed by *et al.* (not italicized and with a period after *al*) and the year if it is the first citation of the reference within a paragraph. …
>
> When a work has six or more authors, cite only the surname of the first author followed by *et al.* (not italicized and with a period after *al*) and the year for the first and subsequent citations.

---

Taking the single-name example referenced in the question, here are some examples of multiple names.

**Two authors:**

> - (J. Smith and B. Jones, personal communication, August 15, 2009)
> - J. Smith and B. Jones (personal communication, August 15, 2009)

**Four authors, first citation:**

> - (J. Smith, B. Jones, C. Walker, and K. Hall, personal communication, August 15, 2009)
> - J. Smith, B. Jones, C. Walker, and K. Hall (personal communication, August 15, 2009)

**Six authors:**

> - (Smith et al., personal communication, August 15, 2009)
> - Smith et al. (personal communication, August 15, 2009)

---

In short, just combine the two different rules.